# How to remember encoding override for particular website in Firefox?

Tags: windows, firefox, encoding

It's possible to change the page encoding in Hamburger Menu > More > Text Encoding or View > Text Encoding.

But after clicking on a link on webpage (within the same domain), this setting is forgotten. I want to browse a site that has broken/wrong encoding, but changing the encoding for each HTML document is frustrating.

How to save the change for the entire domain?

Comment: You would be better off asking the webmaster to fix their broken site ...

Comment: @DavidPostill That's not true for 99% of websites. Their webmasters are not sitting waiting for things to fix. This one in particular is quite old and probably not managed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not have a feature for remembering the change.